# Font conversion from (unknown file type - maybe .pfa) with .afm

Tags: fonts, adobe-indesign, typefaces, mac

I have been given a font that has a .afm file with another file that doesn't actually have a file type. I'm unsure what the file type is meant to be but, on my Mac, when it installs it, it can read the font fine, without the .afm file and it doesn't need to use a file type. I need this converted to use for a client on their website (they have paid for the licence) but I'm unsure how to convert it.

Are there any programs for Mac/online websites that will be able to convert this for me?

I have InDesign and the whole Adobe Suite and have heard some ways of creating your own fonts, maybe this will be able to export the font properly?

Any ideas or useful links would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `afm` file is probably Adobe Font Metrics file, the other file is probably a `pfb` file. The bulk of the font data is in the `pfb` file and the `afm` file is basically metrics, kerning, random descriptive info. I expect this is an "Adobe Type 1" format typeface, or perhaps something older. My memory is fuzzy.

As far as "converting it", you need to specify why it needs converting and to what format.

Here is a link which might point you in the right direction: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/395620

---

I say "maybe" a lot, because this might also just be a forked "file" from the old "Mac OS" dual-fork file system.

Comment: Oh, okay great.  I need it converted to anything BUT a `.pfb` file, so a `.ttf` or `.otf`.  Something I can use to convert to the formats, `.ttf`, `.otf`, `.svg`, `.woff` for web format.  I'll take a look at the Adobe forums link, see if there's anything there that can help. Thanks!